# How to copy SQL table data without duplicates?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called **MovementEntry**

Sample Data:

| Id | Quantity | Price | EntrySort | Product | Movement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 80 | 8$ | Light | Beer | 1 |
| 2 | 70 | 9$ | Dark | Lager | 1 |
| 3 | 40 | 10$ | Dark | Ale | 2 |
| 4 | 55 | 7$ | Red | Vine | 2 |

Sample Output after running the query (below):

| Id | Quantity | Price | EntrySort | Product | Movement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 80 | 8$ | Light | Beer | 1 |
| 2 | 70 | 9$ | Dark | Lager | 1 |
| 3 | 40 | 10$ | Dark | Ale | 2 |
| 4 | 55 | 7$ | Red | Vine | 2 |
| 5 | 80 | 8$ | Light | Beer | 2 |
| 6 | 70 | 9$ | Dark | Lager | 2 |

When I run it a second time it shouldn't do anything since all the **Products** are already in the table.

This is the query that is supposed to copy all the rows with *minimum* **Movement** value into the same table but with the *maximum* **Movement** value only without duplicate **Product**s.

```
INSERT INTO MovementEntry (Quantity, Price, EntrySort, Product, Movement)
(SELECT Quantity, Price, EntrySort, Product, (SELECT MAX(IncOutc) FROM Movement) 
FROM MovementEntry 
WHERE Movement = (SELECT MIN(IncOutc) FROM Movement))
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT Product FROM MovementEntry)
```

But it gives me an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.

On line 5.

**UPDATE**

**Movement** Table Structure (as requested)

| Id | Added At | IncomeOutcome |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-07-02 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-09-02 | 2 |

(Here in the **IncomeOutcome** filed 1 means that Products were received and 2 means that they were sold)

Comment: 1) No `(` needed before the SELECT.

Comment: 2) Do SELECT DISTINCT to avoid duplicates.

Comment: On which line should I remove it?

Comment: The one before the first/main SELECT.

Comment: And also one of the double ) at the end of row 4.

Comment: I did it and there is no error now, but it tells me that `0 rows were affected`, I'll add the screenshot of data

Comment: The NOT EXISTS is the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicates"? I see none of them.

Comment: That `NOT EXISTS` doesn't make sense, it needs a `WHERE` inside it. Remember that whatever you put into the `SELECT` is ignored, you could just as easily put `SELECT NULL` or `SELECT 1 / 0`.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not images.

Comment: @MaciejLos duplicates arent present right now

Comment: I'll add sample data

Comment: Updated with sample output

Comment: See what happens if you just skip the NOT EXISTS.

Comment: @jarlh it updates the table but then it does so again with the products that already exist in the table under the same movement number

Comment: Pleas share movement table structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try now.

```
  with cte as(
    SELECT Quantity, Price, EntrySort, Product, (SELECT MAX(incomeoutcome) FROM Movement)Movement,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by product order by movement) rn
    FROM MovementEntry 
    WHERE Movement = (SELECT MIN(incomeoutcome) FROM Movement) 
    ) 
    INSERT INTO MovementEntry (Quantity, Price, EntrySort, Product, Movement)
    select  Quantity, Price, EntrySort, Product, Movement from cte where rn=1
    and not exists (select * from movemententry m where m.product=cte.product and m.movement=cte.Movement)
```

Comment: It copied some results but it copied the same results after running it again which shouldn't happen

Comment: What do you mean by sharing sample input in text format?

Comment: You already shared in your question. thanks. Is it the desired output what you have shared in your question? Please share structure of movement table.

Comment: Added the structure of the **Movement** table

Comment: The thing is I need it to NOT insert rows that already have the same Product and Movement here

Comment: I have edited my answer please check. It's working. First time it will insert the rows but from second time it will do nothing.